# Optional decimal point in excel's MSO number format field

Tags: excel, format, export-to-excel

The `mso-number-format` field accepts an encoding that determines how numbers get rendered. What format should I use if I want a decimal point displayed if the number contains a decimal and not displayed for whole numbers?

So `12.34` should be displayed as `12.34` and `5` should be displayed as `5`, not `5.00`

Example of how I am using it:

```
<td style="mso-number-format:#,###.##" x:num>1234.56</td>
```